# Button control not functioning properly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I would like to apologize in advance for the title of the question but I don't really know how else I could ask it. Currently I have a button, and all it does is set the visibility of a panel I have to true, but when I click on the button nothing happens. If I set the visibility attribute on the asp control for the panel to `True` in the .aspx file, the panel will show up, just not when I click the button. Below I have posted my code relative to this button.

.aspx code:

```html
<asp:Button ID="btnShowTop5" runat="server" Text="Top 5" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnShowTop5_Click" />
```

In the `page_load` event I set the visibility of the panel to false:

```vb
pnlTop5.Visible = False
```

.aspx code for the panel in question:

```html
<asp:Panel ID="pnlTop5" CssClass="gvTop5Box1" ScrollBars="Auto" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
                    Top 5 Order Codes
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p style="padding: 2px; margin: 2px; width: auto; height: auto; color: cornsilk;">These are you top 5 most used Order Codes.</p>
                <hr style="color: #822402; width: 100%;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="overflow: auto; width: 100%;">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvTop5OC" runat="server" Width="99%" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None"
                        BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="20">
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FEFCEB" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#AF0101" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F6F0C0" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#7E0000" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderCode" HeaderText="Order Code" SortExpression="OrderCode" Visible="True" ReadOnly="True" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Times Used" SortExpression="Quantity" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

VB code for the button click event:

```vb
Protected Sub btnShowTop5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowTop5.Click
    pnlTop5.Visible = True
End Sub
```

As it stands when the button is clicked, nothing happens and I am at a loss as to why, this is the first time I have seen this happen especially for something that seems so simple. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated and if I am missing any information that would help better understand the problem please let me know, I would be happy to supply it.

Comment: Edit: So I copy/pasted the above code, pertaining to this button control, into a new empty solution in an effort to better refine where the problem may lie.  However, in the new test solution the code and button work as intended, on button click the panel is displayed.  While it is nice to know that my code works in a different solution, I am still at a complete loss as to why the identical code would not work in the current solution.

Comment: in the page load perhaps you want to only set if its not a post back: if(!Page.IsPostBack) pnlTop4.Visible = false;

Answer (score 0):

If you put a breakpoint in your PageLoad event, where you are setting the panel visibility to false you are likely to hit the breakpoint twice as sometimes .NET will call the PageLoad event twice (under various circumstances). I believe the visibility is being set back to false after your button handler has set it to true. Consider setting Visible="False" in the aspx page on the panel rather than setting it in code.